# Display generated Google Map image on a web page

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-apps-script

I am using Google Apps Script to create a page, on which I would like to embed maps.  The maps themselves would be static, but the map could be different depending on other parameters (it’s a genealogy page, and I’d like to display a map of birth and death locations, and maybe some other map points, based on a selected individual).

Using Google’s Maps service, I know that I can create a map, with a couple points built in.

```
Function getMapImage() {
  var map = Maps.newStaticMap()
    .setSize(600,400)
    .addMarker('Chicago, Illinois')  // markers would be based on a passed parm; this is just test data
    .addMarker('Pocatello, Idaho');
  // *** This is where I am looking for some guidance
  return();  // obviously, I'm not returning a blank for real
  }
```

Within the map class, there are a number of things I can do with it at this point.

- I could create a URL, and pass that back.  That appears to require an API account, which at this point, I do not have (and ideally, would like to avoid, but maybe I’ll have to do that).  It also appears that I will run into CORB issues with that, which I think is beyond my knowledge (so if that’s the solution, I’ll be back for more guidance).
- I could create a blob as an image, and pass that back to my page.  I have tried this using a few different examples I have found while researching this.

Server Side

```
function getMapImage() {
  var map = Maps.newStaticMap()
    .setSize(600,400)
    .addMarker('Chicago, Illinois')
    .addMarker('Pocatello, Idaho');
    var mapImage = map.getAs("image/png");
    // OR
    // var mapImage = map.getBlob();
  return(mapImage);
  }
```

Page side

```
<div id=”mapDiv”></div>

<script>

  $(function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayMap).getMapImage();
  }

  function displayMap(mapImage) {
    var binaryData = [];
    binaryData.push(mapImage);
    var mapURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: "image/png"}))
    var mapIMG = "<img src=\'" + mapURL + "\'>"
    $('#mapDiv').html(mapIMG);

  }
</script>
```

The page calls getMapImage() on the server, and the return data is sent as a parm to displayMap().

var mapIMG ends up resolving to `<img src='blob:https://n-a4slffdg23u3pai7jxk7xfeg4t7dfweecjbruoa-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/51b3d383-0eef-41c1-9a50-3397cbe83e0d'>`  This version doesn't create any errors in the console, which other options I tried did.  But on the page, I'm just getting the standard 16x16 image not found icon.

I’ve tried a few other things based on what I’ve come across in researching this, but don’t want to litter this post with all sorts of different code snippets.  I’ve tried a lot of things, but clearly not the right thing yet.

What’s the best / correct (dare I ask, simplest) way to build a map with Google’s Map class, and then serve it to a web page?

EDIT: I added a little more detail on how the server and page interact, in response to Tanaike's question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the relationship between the script of `Server Side` and `Page side`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I noticed that your question had been updated your question, just now. I deeply apologize for this. From your updated question, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modification points:

- I think that in your script, Blob is returned from Google Apps Script to Javascript using `google.script.run`. Unfortunately, in the current stage, Blob data cannot be directly sent from from Google Apps Script to Javascript. I think that this might be the reason of your issue.

In this case, I would like to propose to directly create the data URL at the Google Apps Script side. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### Google Apps Script side:

```
function getMapImage() {
  var map = Maps.newStaticMap()
    .setSize(600, 400)
    .addMarker('Chicago, Illinois')
    .addMarker('Pocatello, Idaho');
  var blob = map.getAs("image/png");  // or map.getBlob()
  var dataUrl = `data:image/png;base64,${Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes())}`;
  return dataUrl;
}
```

#### Javascript side:

```
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayMap).getMapImage();
});

function displayMap(mapURL) {
  var mapIMG = "<img src=\'" + mapURL + "\'>"
  $('#mapDiv').html(mapIMG);
}
```

- In your Javascript side, `$(function() {google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayMap).getMapImage();}` is not enclosed by `)`. Please be careful this.

### Note:

- In my environment, when I saw `<div id=”mapDiv”></div>`, this double quote `”` couldn't be used. So if in your environment, an error occurs by `<div id=”mapDiv”></div>`, please modify `”` to `"` like `<div id="mapDiv"></div>`.

### Reference:

- [base64Encode(data)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64encodedata)

Comment: Thank you for the added information.  At first glace, this appears to be working now.  I need to do a little more testing before I accept the answer, but I think this is going to work for me.  Thank you very much!  As for the missing () on the $(function ... that was just a bad copy/paste when I added the edit.  That function is formatted correctly in the original.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could understand about your question by your additional information. Thank you, too.